# How to ensure an app will run in most versions of Android?

Tags: android, debugging, version

I've developed my first app and it worked fine on my phone (Android 2.2). When I tested in a Xoom (Android 3.2), it had lots of bugs, though. I need this app to run in many different versions of Android. How can I develop it and make sure it will, having only an Android 2.2 in hands for tests?

Comment: Could you tell us what the bugs were?

Comment: Use the emulator to test different platform versions and screen sizes. It's not perfect and sometimes really slow, but it's a start.

Comment: @RaghavSood I don't know exactly. I just know it crashed in some features.

Comment: Post logcat traces of that feature. Does it use the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developing with the last version targeted in the manifest while keeping a close eye to back compatibility is how you achieve this with the best efficiency.

Many libraries (ActionBar Sherlock, NotificationCompat2, ....) will help you in making your app back compatible without issues.

I strongly recommend making the app for the last version of Android so it is ready when this version gets some steam instead of targeting whatever version is the most popular right now. It is a bit more work at the beginning, but it will save you many headaches later on.

The emulator will help you test this, the best configuration is to have a terminal with the last version of android at your disposal (this is why the nexus are a very good choice for a dev) and different configurations on the emulator to test back compatibility or other form factors.